# PunBB or FluxBB?

Tags: php, forum, punbb

I'm looking for some **objective** advice about choosing FluxBB instead of PunBB, and vice versa. I need lightweight, but powerful forums. Please can you tell me the pros and cons of each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both bulletin boards, not forums. FluxBB is the fork, it's raison d'être being XHTML strict support (stupid) and UTF-8 usage (good) and 1-click plugins (still planning?).
Wikipedia notes some other differences, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FluxBB

In theory FluxBB is the more developed fork and has seen more security fixes. However at a quick glance it still doesn't use parameterized SQL, nor input filtering (I've just seen some wacky blacklisting code).

I'd agree it matches the "lightweight" aspect. Haven't tried it out, so can't comment on "powerful". You should try it out. http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/details.php?scriptid=407&name=FluxBB